# Can I force a specific layout orientation, but have an opposite keyboard orientation? Android

Tags: android, layout

I understand how to force a specific orientation per activity in the android manifest. I would like to know if it is possible to allow the keyboard to change orientation even though the activity(the layout really) must remain unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry. Orientation is for the full user experience.